# Make sections begin on even-numbered pages in documentclass article

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, double-sided, sections-paragraphs

I've understood that it's easily solved in the `book` class. But is there a simple solution for how to do this in the article class?

Comment: Do you mean `article` or maybe `scrartcl`?

Comment: I meant article

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally you'd want to start on an odd page:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\def\section{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}
```

If you really do want to have the headings on even pages, modify the definition of `\cleardoublepage` (taking out an `\else` to give `\clearevenpage`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}


\let\oldsection\section
\def\section{\clearevenpage\oldsection}

\makeatletter
\def\clearevenpage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
one
\section{aaaa}
one two three
\section{jjaaaa}
one two three four

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right that I want to start on an odd-numbered page. Your solution worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can put

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleartoleftpage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble and then prefix sections with `\cleartoleftpage`.

Answer (score 4):

The following uses [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)'s `strict` mode to set a label for every section and check whether it's odd, issuing the necessary page breaks. It takes a couple of compiles (...number of sections), to stabilize the ToC. The command `\evenpagesection` initiates the sequence:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage
\newcommand{\evenpagesection}{%
  \global\let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand\section{%
    \clearpage\checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage\null\clearpage\fi%
    \oldsection
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\evenpagesection % Start sections on an even page
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```