# Figures on two pages next to each other

Tags: floats

I have a number of figures that I want to have next to each other. Since they do not fit well on one page, I placed them on two pages. Is there a way to make sure that the figures are next to each other such that when the reader opens the book, he sees the figures on the left and right page. And not that one figure is on the backside of the previous one?

thanks!

Comment: For sure there is. It may depend on the packages you're loading, or the document class (which may place restrictions on placement of floats). Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that sets the stage for your usage? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Click on the link for some examples on how to do this with Lorem Ipsum text and [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) images...

Answer (score 3):

First you want to force yourself onto an even (left) page using `\clearevenpage` defined in various places but eg

[Make sections begin on even-numbered pages in documentclass article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51920/make-sections-begin-on-even-numbered-pages-in-documentclass-article/51926#51926)

then

```
\clearevenpage
\begin{figure}[p]
..\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]
..\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: MWE]

Assuming that you want two big images at the top of each page, and there are not previous unprocessed floats, you only need two floats with the `[t]` option. Placements of floats do not need precision shooting: Both can be inserted at some  point in the previous odd page or the even page. This way, you avoid disrupting the flow of text with commands like `\clearpage` .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \setcounter{topnumber}{1} 
% \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.3} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]% dummy text
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[6-14] % more dummy text
\end{document}
```

For smaller images, by default both images will be moved to the top of the even page, but you can limit the number of top images with the  `topnumber` counter, or limit the space for top images with some like `\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.3}`.

Instead, if the floats are placed at the end of the document because are too big for LaTeX rules, increase `\topfraction` and reduce `\textfraction` with the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to restrict images placement in the document:

```
\FloatBarrier

\begin{figure}
Figure 1
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
Figure 2
\begin{figure}

\FloatBarrier
```

If figures fit entire page they will be placed on consequentive pages one after another.

Comment: It's always better to post full examples instead fragments of code. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you. Finally I decided to join the comunity. Just followed the exampe of more experienced user - David Carlise. His answer was nearly identical if it comes to code completeness.