# After adding blank page, two sided option has confused

Tags: margins, double-sided

I am using the two sided option in latex. I need to start my section in the right side of my thesis so because of that sometimes I added a blank page without a page number. After adding blank page, two-sided option confused and mixed the sequence.

How can I handle this problem ?

EDIT:

To add a blank page I use this package and settings.

```
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
```

I added \afterpage{blankpage} command where I want to add a blank page. After the blankpage the sections start and sections should be start at the right side. But they start from the left side. \cleardoublepage creates a new blank page with the page number so that is not intended.

Comment: That depends probably on the document class you use.

Comment: `blank page without a page number` what do you mean?

Comment: The blank page, even if it is empty, stil needs to be numbered. It won't work otherwise.

Comment: it is not clear, what document class are you using, and how did you add the blank page ? did you use `\clearpage`  `\cleardoublepage` ? a MWE would help us help you

Comment: @EladDen I updated my question. Could you please check again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command does not add a blank page, it simply moves to a new page. Therefore if your section ends at page 3, `\blankpage` will move to the new page, which is 4.

You should use `\cleardoublepage`. It is right that this generates a page with header and footer, for that we can use the `emptypage` package.

You can also redefine the `\section` in your document, so that you won't have to retype `\cleardoublepage` after each section with the `\let` `\def` commands.

here is a MWE of what I suggest:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\let\oldsection\section
\def\section{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section1}
    \lipsum[1-13]
    \section{Section2}
    \lipsum[14-25]
\end{document}
```

Right and left definitions are quite tricky as they depend on the binding (or lack of which). I added fancyhdr so that it would be clear which page is odd and which is even. I assumed you wanted your sections on the odd pages. If you want them on the even take a look at this [Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51926/90297)